# Why my .NET controller acts in a case sensitive way on one machine?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this controller and action:

```
public class EntityTagController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object All(string entityType)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

It works just fine on the machine of my colleagues. But on my machine, it works if I call it as `/EntityTag/All` and it returns 404 if I call it as `/entityTag/all`.

What can cause this error?

Comment: Same config, same runtime, same OS, same C#/.NET version?

Comment: How are you hosting it for your debug environment?

Comment: @knittl, same everything. I runs inside a docker container.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, the same `docker-compose.json` that uses Microsoft's base image. And the container goes behind an Nginx proxy

Comment: And on your coworkers machine does it also go behind the Nginx proxy? Could the proxy being a source of the case sensitivity?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, the same Nginx config file is created for all of team members.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, thank you so much. You helped me realize the problem. I'm working on a multilingual solution using Nginx, and I had added `location /en` to my local config file to test it. That `/en` would cause the case-sensitivity.